# How to select existing sheet to be populated by a Google form?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-forms, google-sheets-query, import

I have a team working in pan India with 6 Team leaders. I have created a Google form to collect the everyday status report.
**Now the question is:**

How can I assign a particular sheet[already created in google spreadsheet with a team name]  of google spreadsheet as a destination?
If I go to response sheet option in google form, it is asking existing sheet ? or new sheet. If I give the option as *existing sheet*, it selects already existing sheet but, creates a new sheet in the existing sheet. 
I want to select my destination sheet.
Any help?

for eg:
**Sheet1,  Sheet2,  Sheet3** are existing sheets in google sheet book.
I want to select **sheet2** as a response destination sheet. 
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, this is not achievable and a workaround is to have Google form to populate deafult sheet and then use **`QUERY`** or similar functions to import your data in **Sheet2** with an option of hiding the form sheet by right-clicking on the sheet and selecting **Hide sheet**.

[image]